# Passing array of reg expressions to spring based mongo @Query

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using Spring boot with mongodb. I've extended PagingAndSortingRepository repository and added the following function

```
@Query("{'title':{ $nin: [?0]}}")
List<Item> findItem(String[] exclude);
```

I want to be able to pass it an array of regular expressions such as /dog/,/cat/,/horse/  to exclude any item that may have one of these in it's title.

The above function does not work because the exclude is converted to a string. How can I pass an array of regular expressions to be able to do the above?

Comment: It seems you put your finger on *the* case that can't be directly solved with "standard" query methods or with the @Query annotation (as of today). Do you plan to use your repository instance in a controller? If so I may have an idea.

Comment: Yes I am using the repo in a @RestController instance. I was thinking of converting the array into a single regex and use $regex instead but it's not a very clean solution.

Comment: Your single regex would probably include pipes and I'm pretty sure Spring does respond well to pipes in URLs.

Comment: You're probably correct. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work it out by using a [Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/) predicate in one of your controller method.

Add something like this to your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/search/findByNameRegexNotIn", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Item> findByNameRegexNotIn(@RequestParam(name = "name") List<String> names) {
    // build a query predicate
    BooleanBuilder predicate = new BooleanBuilder();  // comes from the Querydsl library
    for (String name : names) {
            predicate.and(QItem.item.name.contains(name).not()); // the QItem class is generated by Querydsl
    }

    List<Item> items = (List<Item>)repository.findAll(predicate);

    return items;
}
```

You can of course add a Pageable parameter and return a Page<Item> instead of a List.

Edit: another solution if you use Querydsl for this sole purpose is to override the default bindings of your query parameter.

```
public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, String>,
    QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Item>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QItem> {

    @Override
    default public void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QItem item) {
        bindings.bind(item.name).all(
            (path, values) ->  path.matches(StringUtils.collectionToDelimitedString(values, "|")).not());
        // disable query on all parameters but the item name
        bindings.including(item.name);
        bindings.excludeUnlistedProperties(true);
    }
}
```

The controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/search/query", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Item> queryItems(
        @QuerydslPredicate(root = Item.class) Predicate predicate) {
        List<Item> items = (List<Item>)repository.findAll(predicate);

        return items;
    }
```

Edit: if you don't wan't to override the default QuerydslBinderCustomizer#customize, you can also implement your own binder and specify it in the controller method.

```
public interface ItemRepository extends CrudRepository<Item, String>,
    QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Item> {
    ...
}
```

The controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/search/query", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public List<Item> queryItems(
        @QuerydslPredicate(root = Item.class, bindings = ItemBinder.class) Predicate predicate) {
        List<Item> items = (List<Item>)repository.findAll(predicate);

        return items;
    }
```

The binder class:

```
class ItemBinder implements QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QItem> {

@Override
public void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QItem item) {
    bindings.bind(item.name).all(
            (path, values) ->  path.matches(StringUtils.collectionToDelimitedString(values, "|")).not()
    );
    bindings.including(item.name);
    bindings.excludeUnlistedProperties(true);
}
```

}

Edit: for the sake of exhaustivity and those who don't want to hear about Querysl. Using the solution proposed in [Spring Data Mongodb Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour).

Define a custom repository interface:

```
interface ItemRepositoryCustom {

    public Page<Item> findByNameRegexIn(Collection<String> names, Pageable page);

}
```

Define an custom repository implementation (*Impl* postfix required!):

```
public class ItemRepositoryImpl implements ItemRepositoryCustom {

    @Autowired
    private MongoOperations operations;

    @Override
    public Page<Item> findByNameRegexNotIn(Collection<String> names, Pageable pageable) {
        String pattern = StringUtils.collectionToDelimitedString(names, "|");
        // this time we use org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query instead of Querydsl predicates
        Query query = Query.query(where("name").regex(pattern).not()).with(pageable);

        List<Item> items = operations.find(query, Item.class);
        Page<Item> page = new PageImpl<>(items, pageable, items.size());

        return page;
    }

}
```

Now simply extend ItemRepositoryCustom:

```
public interface ItemRepository extends MongoRepository<Item, String>, ItemRepositoryCustom {

...

}
```

And you're done!

Comment: Thank you! will give it a try and get back to you.

Comment: @jvence I edited my answer with an alternative solution (I discovered interesting things thanks to you ;) )

Comment: @jvence And a third (and last) alternative.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using the first method and it seems to be working well. I think Spring should support this with the @Query method.

Comment: Then I suggest you to open a feature request on the Spring Data MongoDB [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO).

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `java.util.regex.Pattern[]` to the method. This will be converted to regex array under the hood:

```java
@Query("{'title':{ $nin: ?0}}")
List<Item> findItem(Pattern[] exclude);
```