# Spring Data MongoDB NotLike - Unsupported keyword

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have configured a Spring Data Repository (mongoDB) and Author entity as following :

```
Repository :
   public interface AuthorRepository extends MongoRepository< Author, Long > {
        Iterable<Author> findByFirstName( String personName );
        Iterable<Author> findByFirstNameLike( String personName );
        Iterable<Author> findByFirstNameNotLike( String firstName );
    }
Entity Class :   
    @Document( collection = "author" )
    @Data
    public class Author {
        @Id
        private String          id;

        private String          firstName;

      //..
    }
```

I'm able to run the first two queries without any errors. But the "NotLike" method gives me following runtime error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported keyword!
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryCreator.from(MongoQueryCreator.java:252) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryCreator.create(MongoQueryCreator.java:114) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryCreator.create(MongoQueryCreator.java:58) ~[spring-data-mongodb-1.8.4.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ...
```

I looked into `MongoQueryCreator.from(MongoQueryCreator.java:252)` and found `Part.Type.NOT_LIKE` is not handled on `switch-case` statement there and its throwing `IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported keyword!");`

Spring Data MongoDB [latest documentation (1.8.4.RELEASE)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords) says NotLike is a supported query keyword. But it seems to be missing in the implementation.

Is there anything missing here or I should raise a bug fix ?

Comment: You need post more source code, I don't see query statement.

Comment: I'm using spring-data-mongodb repository, no query is needed to present ! The repository is extending MongoRepository - which takes care of everything.

Comment: `findByFirstNameNotLike` is not supported. Let's see **Table 6.1. Supported keywords for query methods**  http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.2.x/reference/html/mongo.repositories.html or try to use normal query.

Comment: you are looking at the old version. i'm using 1.8.4.RELEASE(latest as of now)

Comment: Let's see **Table 3. Supported keywords for query methods** in http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.8.4.RELEASE/reference/html/ . I don't see keyword `notLike`yet. Lastest version is `1.9.1.RELEASE` http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: hmm.. the Appendix C at bottom of page mentions NotLike and several other which are not in Table 3. it says :  [  The following table lists the keywords generally supported by the Spring Data repository query derivation mechanism. However, consult the store-specific documentation for the exact list of supported keywords, because some listed here might not be supported in a particular store. ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Spring Data MongoDB latest documentation (1.8.4.RELEASE) says NotLike
>   is a supported query keyword. But it seems to be missing in the
>   implementation.

*NotLike* is still not supported in the current (1.9.1) release of Spring Data MongoDB - see [Table 5. Supported keywords for query methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries).

> Is there anything missing here or I should raise a bug fix ?

Not a bug fix, since the runtime error is consistent with the keyword not being supported, but you can open a feature request on the Spring Data MongoDB [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO).

In the mean time, to get your code running, you can implement your own *findByFirstNameNotLike* method, using the [Query](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.json-based) annotation or even [Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/) for [more complex queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36600550/5873923).

Comment: I've opened [DATAMONGO-1424](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1424) to add support for `notLike`.

Comment: Thanks @ChristophStrobl. Do you think it would be reasonable to ask support for other "Like" or "Regex" keywords, such as "InRegex" (matching against an array of regex) and [NotInRegex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600550/passing-array-of-reg-expressions-to-spring-based-mongo-query)? I for one could have used it in the past, and I've seen similar questions on SO a few times already.

Comment: please just open an issue for `inRegex` and `notInRegex` in [Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS) so that there's the opportunity to vote for it. thanks!