# Spring CrudRepository - find ignore case in collection

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I figured since the syntax for an `ignore case` query is:

```
findByFieldIgnoreCase(Object field)
```

And the syntax for a `collection` query is

```
findByFieldIn(List<Object> fields)
```

The syntax for an `ignore case collection` query would be:

```
findByFieldIgnoreCaseIn(List<Object> fields)
```

But that doesn't seem to work (it's still case sensitive).

Ideas?

EDIT:

It's not `findByFieldInIgnoreCase` as well.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `findByFieldInIgnoreCase(..)` ? (if that even matters)

Comment: Nope, tried that too :\

Answer (score 1):

The [Spring Data MongoDB Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation) states that:

> The method parser supports setting an IgnoreCase flag for individual
>   properties (for example, findByLastnameIgnoreCase(…)) or for all
>   properties of a type that support ignoring case (usually String
>   instances, for example, findByLastnameAndFirstnameAllIgnoreCase(…)).
>   Whether ignoring cases is supported may vary by store, so consult the
>   relevant sections in the reference documentation for the
>   store-specific query method.

The table of [supported keywords for query methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries) does not explicitly mention an *InIgnoreCase* or *IgnoreCaseIn* keyword.

As for other [unsupported keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36662697/5873923), you can open a feature request on the Spring Data MongoDB [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO/).

In the mean time, to get your code running, you can implement your own *findByFieldIgnoreCaseIn* of *findByFieldInIgnoreCase* using the [Query](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.json-based) annotation or [Querydsl](http://www.querydsl.com/). I offered several possible solutions for a similar case in this other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36647967/5873923).

Answer (score 0):

```
findByFieldInAndIgnoreCase(List<Object> fields)
```

This should work its not throwing any error while starting application.

Comment: No. "not throwing any error while starting application" != works.