# Spring with Query Dsl custom binding and or operation doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, filter, binding, querydsl

i have following reQuirement Query:

"/article?**category**=kitchen&**category**=sports"

This Query is working without custom bindings. It will give me all Kitchen and sports articles as Response. It is doing an OR-Operation somehow.

But i need to customize the binding because i need to ingore the case. Now i am using this customize binding:

```
@Repository
public interface ArticleRepository extends JpaRepository<Article, Long>, 
QueryDslPredicateExecutor<QArticle>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QArticle> {


 @Override
  default public void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QArticle article) {

     bindings.bind(String.class).first((StringPath path, String value) -> path.containsIgnoreCase(value));
  }
}
```

This only filters the **first available** value of a attribut. So in this case it only gives articles in category kitchen as Response. The second value of the category (sports) is ignored.

And now my Question: How can i get the articles of **both** catergories ignoring the case sensetive? What i need to change in my customize binding to achieve that?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 6):

The correct bindings for your `article.category` property should be like this:

```
bindings.bind(article.category).all((path, value) -> {
    BooleanBuilder predicate = new BooleanBuilder();
    value.forEach(o -> predicate.or(path.equalsIgnoreCase(o)));
    return Optional.of(predicate);
});
```

If you don't need any manipulations of the parameters (like ignoring case) you can simplify it to that:

```
bindings.bind(article.category).all((path, value) -> Optional.of(path.in(value)));
```

Answer (score 5):

QuerydslBindings.TypeBinder#first uses a [single value binding](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/querydsl/binding/SingleValueBinding.html). You need to use QuerydslBindings.TypeBinder#[all](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/querydsl/binding/QuerydslBindings.TypeBinder.html#all-org.springframework.data.querydsl.binding.MultiValueBinding-). This method operates on a 
 [multivalue binding](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/querydsl/binding/MultiValueBinding.html).

I provided several examples of how to customize your bindings in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36647967/5873923). Something like this should work for you:

```
@Override
default public void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QArticle article) {
    // using explicit path bindings
    bindings.bind(article.category).all((path, values) -> {
        BooleanBuilder predicate = new BooleanBuilder();
        // with a for loop
        for (String value : values) {
            predicate.or(path.containsIgnoreCase(value));
        }
    });

    // using a type binding
    bindings.bind(String.class).all((StringPath path, Collection<? extends String> values) -> {
        BooleanBuilder predicate = new BooleanBuilder();
        // oneliner with Java 8 forEach
        values.forEach( value -> predicate.or(path.containsIgnoreCase(value) );
    });

}
```

Comment: Actually with your example it's not working. I cant use the .all() mehtod: The method all(MultiValueBinding<StringPath,String>) in the type QuerydslBindings.PathBinder<StringPath,String> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> path, <no type> values) -> {})

Comment: If I remember correctly, it does indeed not work with  `bind(Class<T> type) `parameter, but it should work with `bind(T... paths)`.

Comment: @EmreÖztürk explicitely mentioning StringPath and Collection<? extends String> for the lambda parameters did the trick.

Answer (score 5):

After a good search on it I found the solution.

```
 bindings.bind(String.class).all(new MultiValueBinding<StringPath, String> () {
        @Override
        public Predicate bind(StringPath path, Collection<? extends String> values) {
            BooleanBuilder predicate = new BooleanBuilder();
            values.forEach( value -> predicate.or(path.containsIgnoreCase(value)));
            return predicate;
        }
    });
```

Comment: It says customize does not implement abstract method , it expects as parametrers, instead of new MultiValueBind, StringPath and Collection<>.

Comment: With later versions, you'll need to return `Optional<Predicate>`