# Search where A or B with querydsl and spring data rest

Tags: spring-data-rest, querydsl

http://localhost:8080/users?firstName=a&lastName=b ---> where firstName=a and lastName=b
How to make it to or ---> where firstName=a or lastName=b

But when I set QuerydslBinderCustomizer customize

```
@Override
default public void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QUser user) {
    bindings.bind(String.class).all((StringPath path, Collection<? extends String> values) -> {
        BooleanBuilder predicate = new BooleanBuilder();
        values.forEach( value -> predicate.or(path.containsIgnoreCase(value) );
    });

}
```

http://localhost:8080/users?firstName=a&firstName=b&lastName=b ---> where (firstName=a or firstName = b) and lastName=b

It seem different parameters with AND. Same parameters with what I set(predicate.or/predicate.and)

How to make it different parameters with AND like this ---> where firstName=a or firstName=b or lastName=b ??
thx.

Comment: You will need to look at customizing the QueryDSl bindings. See this answer as a starting point. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42715480/1356423

Comment: http://localhost:8080/users?A=a&A=b&B=b ---> where (A=a or A = b) and B=b

How to make it to ---> where A=a or A=b or B=b

Comment: As noted, I believe you would need to look at customizing the bindings. The answer I have given should be enough to get you started.

Comment: I can't fix it . It seem different parameters with AND. Same parameters with BooleanBuilder().or()...

Comment: I find some code in QuerydslPredicateBuilder.java   predicate.ifPresent(builder::and);   It default AND?

Comment: Maybe the simplest solution then is to write a Spring MVC controller that builds the predicate by hand and returns the results.

Comment: @cbyniiaii did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Your current request param are grouped as List firstName and String lastName. I see that you want to keep your request parameters without a binding, but in this case it would make your life easier.

My suggestion is to make a new class with request param:

```
public class UserRequest {
    private String lastName;
    private List<String> firstName;
    // getters and setters
}
```

For QueryDSL, you can create a builder object:

```
 public class UserPredicateBuilder{

     private List<BooleanExpression> expressions = new ArrayList<>();

     public UserPredicateBuilder withFirstName(List<String> firstNameList){
          QUser user = QUser.user;
          expressions.add(user.firstName.in(firstNameList));
          return this;
     }
     //.. same for other fields

     public BooleanExpression build(){
        if(expressions.isEmpty()){
           return Expressions.asBoolean(true).isTrue();
        }
        BooleanExpression result = expressions.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < expressions.size(); i++) {
           result = result.and(expressions.get(i));
        }
        return result;
     }
 }
```

And after you can just use the builder as :

```
 public List<User> getUsers(UserRequest userRequest){
       BooleanExpression expression = new UserPredicateBuilder()
                                      .withFirstName(userRequest.getFirstName())
                                    // other fields
                                      .build();
       return userRepository.findAll(expression).getContent();
 }
```

This is the recommended solution.
If you really want to keep the current params without a binding (they still need some kind of validation, otherwise it can throw an Exception in query dsl binding)
you can group them by path :

`Map<StringPath,List<String>> values` // example firstName => a,b

and after that to create your boolean expression based on the map:

```
   //initial value
  BooleanExpression result = Expressions.asBoolean(true).isTrue();
  for (Map.Entry entry: values.entrySet()) {
       result = result.and(entry.getKey().in(entry.getValues());
  }
  return userRepository.findAll(result);
```

Comment: I want to use with spring data rest. So I can't do that in the interface like  userRepository.findAll