# Using Querydsl for filtering operations

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I just started learning querydsl. I want to do simple filter operations. I saw that there are 2 different methods to do this. The first one is with bindings using the **@QuerydslPredicate** annotation, the second one is by creating a **custom predicate**. Using **@QuerydslPredicate** annotation I can't use operators like ">, <, >=, <=, !" etc. I couldn't get through. I read https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-querydsl as reference for this. I created 2 classes for the example.

```
@Entity
public class Author {
   private String name;
   private Integer age;

   @ManyToMany
   private Set<Book> books;
}

@Entity
public class Book {
   private String name;

   @ManyToMany
   private Set<Author> authors;
}
```

Http requests I want are

```
GET "http://localhost:8080/api/author?filter=age>30"
OR
GET "http://localhost:8080/api/author?age>30" 

/*
* Join operation
* Get the authors of the book named Harry potter.
*/
GET "http://localhost:8080/api/author?filter=books.name:HarryPotter"
OR
GET "http://localhost:8080/api/author?books.name=HarryPotter"
```

I would be very happy if you support it with sample codes.

Comment: A little inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36647967/5873923

Comment: Thanks but this is not I wanted. I want more than one bind for Integer.class. For example these binds support ">" and "<" operations.

Comment: Use [multivalue binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42715480/5873923). But you can't use QueryDSL to match "filter" since it's not defined in your domain object. Your query string must look like `?age=30&age=40&name=` and the behavior of the bindings must be defined in QuerydslPredicateExecutor#customize. You could use lower and upper bounds for `age` , for instance.